# How to get Burgers hierarchy for any value of n

Tags: operators

The Burgers hierarchy is defined by

```
D[u[t, x], t] + α D[((∂/∂x) + u[t, x])^n u[t, x], x]
```

How can I get the equation for the value of `n = 1, 2, ...`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: It is customary to either (a) accept answers that answer your question by clicking the grey check mark next to the answer or (b), comment on the answer to let the answerer know how they can fix their solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
n = 2;
D[u[t, x], t] + α D[Nest[D[#, x] + u[t, x] # &, u[t, x], n], x] // Expand
```

[image: screenshot of result]

Comment: +1, but, is it correct? Shouldn't e.g. `n=1` give the Burgers's equation, `2*alpha*u[t, x]*Derivative[0, 1][u][t, x] + alpha*Derivative[0, 2][u][t, x] + 
 Derivative[1, 0][u][t, x]`? (`n=2` case is called the Sharma-Tasso-Olver equation, apparently.)

Comment: Now it's right. You missed the outer `D` for the second term.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, @OleksandrR. Yeah, I simply forgot that extra derivative once I figured out the `Nest` thing. I'm not actually familiar with this set of equations, but the OP had enough info in the question to write an answer.